# I can't redirect to Route in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

everyone. 
I am building symphony 5 project, but I have an issue.
The URL is not redirecting after I create or edit an element.
But in other functions, the redirectToRoute() function works.
Strange problem...

These are my controller code.
Please check it and let me know what I missed. 
Thanks.

```
/**
 * @Route("/list", name="animals")
 */
public function animals(): Response
{
    if (!$this->getUser()) {
        $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
    }

    $animals = $this->getUser()->getAnimals();

    return $this->render('animals/overview.html.twig', [
        'animals' => $animals,
    ]);
}
```

And

```
/**
 * @Route("/create", name="animal_create")
 */
public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $animal = new Animal();
    $customer = $this->em()->getRepository(Customer::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->request->get('customer')));
    $animal->setCustomer($customer);

    $form = $this->createForm(AnimalType::class, $animal, [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if (!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid()) {
        return new Response('failed');
    }

    $customer->addAnimal($animal);

    $entityManager->persist($animal);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('animals');
}


/**
 * @Route("/{id}/update", name="animal_update")
 */
public function update(Request $request, Animal $animal, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(AnimalType::class, $animal, [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if (!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid()) {
        return new Response('failed');
    }

    $entityManager->persist($animal);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('animals');
}
```

Comment: You're processing the form incorrectly. [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms) is an example of how to handle and process a form when submitted and redirect etc..

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? Also `RePSonse` is incorrect class name.

Comment: In your first code example within the if you aren't returning the redirect response

Comment: When I submit the form, the data is changed and saved in the db correctly. But the page isn't redirected to a list page.

Answer (score 0):

You must redirect to the index route only if the form is submitted and validated, otherwise the form must be displayed.
The [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms) explains this perfectly:

```php
public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $animal = new Animal();
    $customer = $this->em()->getRepository(Customer::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->request->get('customer')));
    $animal->setCustomer($customer);

    $form = $this->createForm(AnimalType::class, $animal);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $animal = $form->getData();

        $customer->addAnimal($animal);

        $entityManager->persist($animal);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('animals');
    }

    // Here it's the name of your twig template for animal creation
    return $this->renderForm('animal/create.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Do the same thing for the update action.